# Is there way to increase speed of burning subtitles to a video in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-subtitles

Currently, I do it this way: `ffmpeg -i video.mkv -vf subtitles=video.mkv out.mp4` But with some videos, it takes too long around 55mins but with handbrake, it takes only 10 mins to burn subtitle to video even though I tweaked the setting for instances enabling **ultrafast** mode. Is there a way to increase the speed of that: maybe saving output files with the lesser quality or something?

Comment: for handbrake , preset is 'very fast 1080p' and encoder preset is 'ultrafast' , for ffmpeg i only used 'ffmpeg -i video.mkv -vf subtitles=video.mkv out.mp4' is there way to speed the process?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [x264 `-preset`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264):

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -vf subtitles=video.mkv -preset ultrafast out.mp4
```

If `video.mkv` contains AAC audio, then add the `-c:a copy` output option to [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the audio instead of re-encoding it.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer , are they any cons of using ultrafast mode or fast in general.

Comment: @AhmedYasir Faster presets are less efficient at compression, so file size will be bigger. Use the slowest preset you can.